# Python: Remove apostrophes outside key strings

Tags: python

Is there any other way to remove apostrophes outside the key strings? For example, the `'value'` must only be value within the dictionary. I tried replace() function but nothing happens.

```
resultSet = [{'name':'Taylor Swift','key':'hui7'}, {'name':'Lady Gaga','key':'bu5u'}]

emplist = []

for emp in resultSet:
    value = "value"
    empdict = {
    value.replace("'",""): emp['name'],
'uid'.replace("'", ""): 'key:' + emp['key']}
    emplist.append(empdict)

print(emplist)
>> [{'value': 'Taylor Swift', 'uid': 'key:hui7'}, {'value': 'Lady Gaga', 'uid': 'key:bu5u'}]
```

Expected result

```
print(emplist)
>> [{value: 'Taylor Swift', uid: 'key:hui7'}, {value: 'Lady Gaga', uid: 'key:bu5u'}]
```

After I modified Yaroslav's solution, I got my expected result.

```
resultSet = [{'name':'Taylor Swift','key_fk':'hui7'},{'name':'Lady Gaga','key_fk':'bu5u'}]

loop = ', '.join("{value: '{}', uid: 'key: {}'}".format(item['name'], item['key_fk']) for item in resultSet)

result = '[' + loop + ']'
print(result)
>> [{value: 'Taylor Swift', uid: 'key: hui7'}, {value: 'Lady Gaga', uid: 'key: bu5u'}]
```

Comment: No, you can't, and you shouldn't. You make it near impossible for anything else to work with that data once you do that sort of stuff to it.

Comment: `key` or `uid`? That is the question!

Comment: The purpose of it is to fetch it on an html file like this: <script> $('.label').labelinput({ source: [{value: 'Taylor Swift', uid: 'key:hui7'}, {value: 'Lady Gaga', uid: 'key:bu5u'}] }); </script>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on Jom's comment to question, I assume that following pseudo-snippet could do the trick:

```
resultSet = [
    {
        'name': 'Taylor Swift',
        'key': 'hui7'
    }, {
        'name': 'Lady Gaga',
        'key': 'bu5u'
    }
]

result = []

for item in resultSet:
    result.append(
        "{%s}" % ', '.join(
            ["{0}: '{1}'".format(key, value) for key, value in item.items()]
        )
    )

print(result)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
result = ', '.join(
        "{%s}" % ', '.join(
            ["%s: '%s'" % (key, value) for key, value in item.items()]
        ) for item in resultSet
    )

result = '[' + result + ']'
print(result)
```

Please note, that this solution is **NOT** pythonic.
For your purpouses you should use some template language ( for example: jinja2 )

Comment: I ran your code and here's the result: ["{name: 'Taylor Swift', key: 'hui7'}", "{name: 'Lady Gaga', key: 'bu5u'}"]. I just want [{value: 'Taylor Swift', uid: 'key:hui7'},{value: 'Lady Gaga', uid: 'key:bu5u'}] like what DYZ did, but I don't understand his answer where to put those lines.

Comment: You can iterate over the resulting list of strings and insert them in your html

Comment: I don't need to iterate the list as possible, I just need to create a one-way result.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thank you. I use Flask and obviously jinja2, this is not a recommendable answer to everyone, it's just happened that a jquery needs an input like that. :)

Comment: I will add some example using Jinja2 if you dont mind.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not any way because the `'` represent that it is a `String`. So it is not actually present. For example, if you have `'value'`, the first character of this is `v` and the last is `e`. `Replace()` does not work because it only replaces the something that is present in the string but since the `'` aren't present in the string, there is nothing to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want that?

Dictionaries are better to work with.

If you just want the name :

```
[i['value'] for i in emplist]
```

It will return:

```
 ['Taylor Swift', 'Lady Gaga']
```

Besides it will raise a ValueError if the variable are not defined.

Perhaps it could help if you say what exactly are you trying to achieve here, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you work with data the easy way?

```
import json
resultSet = [{'name':'Taylor Swift','key':'hui7'}, {'name':'Lady Gaga','key':'bu5u'}]
json.dumps(resultSet)
```

Comment: I want to remove the apostrophes outside the strings of key, please re-read my question above.

Comment: i have read, i was just talking about the utility on your comment "<script> $('.label').labelinput({ source: [{value: 'Taylor Swift', uid: 'key:hui7'}, {value: 'Lady Gaga', uid: 'key:bu5u'}] }); </script>" if you want use for that, json libraries will probably be more efficient than your solution, i was suggesting you to reconsider your approach, and its the industry standard